# Query simplification Oracle Northwind

Tags: sql, database, oracle, northwind

**Task  :**

Find country to which maximum of customers belong.

**Query**

```
SELECT country,
       count(*)
FROM customers
GROUP BY country
HAVING count(*) =
  (SELECT max(max_sal)
   FROM
     (SELECT count(*) max_sal
      FROM customers
      GROUP BY country)) ;
```

**Result**:

[image]

The Result is correct but i think it is difficult way to write query

**Question :** Is there any simple way to rewrite this query.

Comment: can you use window functions?

Comment: @vkp i never user use window function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be missing something, but it can be as simple as this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (  SELECT country, COUNT (*) max_sal
            FROM customers
        GROUP BY country
        ORDER BY COUNT (*) DESC)
 WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WITH` clause:

```
WITH
  c AS ( 
    SELECT country, Count(1) n
    FROM customers
    GROUP BY country)
SELECT country, n 
FROM c
WHERE n = (SELECT Max(n) FROM c)
```

Answer (score 1):

U can use analytic function over() wich u get result of max (avg, min, etc..) on every row of result and then in where compare count(1) and max(count(1))

here is example:

```
SELECT country, cnt, max_cnt
  FROM (SELECT country, COUNT(1) AS cnt, MAX(COUNT(1)) over() max_cnt
           FROM customers
          GROUP BY country)
 WHERE cnt = max_cnt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Country, MAX(N) FROM (
    SELECT Country, COUNT(*) as N FROM CUSTOMERS GROUP BY Country
);
```